# ASP.NET MVC Scripts.Render not merging files..?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've noticed `<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/jqueryval"></script>`

Will merge the files into a single HTTP request

But if I use the @Scripts.render I.E `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

They are still separate HTTP requests/files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are running in Release mode:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

if you want the scripts to be minified and bundled into a single one.

Comment: You can also force it by code with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` at `BundleConfig`

Answer (score 5):

You can also force it by code with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` at `BundleConfig`

***by popular request I add it as an answer***